# Get IP address info (gateway and subnet too) on Ubuntu or Debian using bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu, awk

I am trying to get the IP address of the ethernet or wifi adapter on Debian and Ubuntu systems using bash. I can get it reliably using ifconfig but it requires net-tools to be installed which is now deprecated but it does work.

```
showip=$(ifconfig eth0 | awk -F"[: ]+" '/inet addr:/ {print $4}')
```

I have made something using ip route but it doesn't work consistently, sometimes the outputted lines are different depending on the distro and version

```
MAINIP=$(ip route | awk 'NR==3{print $9}')
GATEWAYIP=$(ip route | awk 'NR==1{print $3}')
SUBNET=$(ip route | awk 'NR==2{print $1}')
```

Is there a way to grep or awk using regular expressions to ensure it works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do:

```
MAINIP=$(ip addr show dev eth0 | grep "inet" | awk 'NR==1{print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f 1)
```

For subnet you could then:

```
SUBNET=$(ip route | grep "src $MAINIP" | awk '{print $1}')
```

And for GW:

```
GATEWAYIP=$(ip route show | grep default | awk '{print $3}')
```

Comment: `ip addr` is one of the least appreciated Linux networking commands.  `ifconfig` is the first thing people run into and so few look for something else.

Comment: Thanks that works for the IP, got ideas for gateway and subnet?

Comment: Updated to include wifi as well since that is what ip route will do I believe.

Comment: I edit my answer to include how I would extract gw/subnet

Comment: @D.K. Awesome, just need one that does wireless too (my fault for not specifying that in original question, updated it now). The issue is it can be wlan0, ra0 etc though ra0 is rare

Comment: What do you mean by wireless? Isn't it just like any other interface?

Comment: How about... `WIFIDEV=$(ip link | egrep "(wlan0|ra0)" | grep -i UP |  awk -F ': ' '{print $2}' | head -n 1)`

This would return you the first wireless device that has its link up.

And then you can substitute eth0 in the command I wrote up for MAINIP with $WIFIDEV

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out which works for wireless connections and not just eth0 (thank you @D.K.), only adjustment was for MAINIP. There may be an even better way or something I am overlooking though.

```
MAINIP=$(ip route | grep src | awk '{print $9}')
GATEWAYIP=$(ip route | grep default | awk '{print $3}')
SUBNET=$(ip route | grep proto | grep -v default | awk '{print $1}')
```

SUBNET without double grep

```
SUBNET=$(ip route | awk '/proto/ && !/default/ {print $1}')
```